# Finding the mass of a wire bent in the shape of a curve $r(t) = (3t,3t^2,2t^3)$ where $0 < t < 1$ if density at $r(t)$ is $1+t$ gram per unit length.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$p = m/V$, so $m = pV = (p/l)(l/V)$. I should just be trying to find the volume and total length?

Comment: Are you familiar with line integrals? See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field.

Comment: @eranreches unfortunately no, I those were in a lecture I missed

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

> If the body is not homogeneous, then its density varies between different regions of the object. In that case the density around any given location is determined by calculating the density of a small volume around that location. In the limit of an infinitesimal volume the density of an inhomogeneous object at a point becomes: $ρ( {\displaystyle {\vec {r}}}) = dm/dV$, where $dV$ is an elementary volume at position r. The mass of the body then can be expressed as :
>
> $$m = \int_V p(\vec{r})dV$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets denote by $\lambda\left(t\right)$ the mass per unit length. Then the mass of the curve $r\left(t\right)$ is given by

$$m=\int_{\ell}\lambda{\rm d}s=\int_{0}^{1}\lambda\left(t\right)\left\|r^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right\|{\rm d}t$$

This is a line integral of the first kind, or a line integral of scalar function as Wikipedia says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field). You are basically dividing the wire into small portions of length ${\rm d}s=\left\|r^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right\|{\rm d}t$ such that the mass of each element is ${\rm d}m=\lambda{\rm d}s$, and then you sum over them (note that this argument is not rigorous, but is very useful in illustrating the point). Can you take it from here?

Comment: I believe that I can. Thank you.

Comment: actually, since $r(t)$ is a vector, wont't I need an iterated integral of some sort? I've differentiate $r(t)$ and set up the integral.

Comment: $\left\|r^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right\|$ is the norm of the tangent to the curve. **This is a scalar** which represents the velocity of the parametrization at $t$.

Comment: Indeed you're correct, I completely ignored the absolute value for some reason. Thank you.